# Hibernate cannot mapping 2 models

Tags: java, hibernate

I have test platform which have 2 models with ManyToOne connection. Aaaaaand this is doesn't work.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tests")
public class Test {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String name;
private int count;
private String description;
private boolean free;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
private User tAuthor;
private String section;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "qTest", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
private String commentToAdmin;
@Column(length = 32, columnDefinition = "varchar(32) default 'Developing'")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private TestStatus status = TestStatus.Developing;
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp createdOn;
@UpdateTimestamp
private Timestamp updateDateTime;
```

models 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String passwordConfirm;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "tAuthor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Test> listTests = new ArrayList<Test>();
private Set<Role> roles;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rUser", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<Result> result = new ArrayList<Result>();
@CreationTimestamp
private Timestamp dateRegistration;
```

Exception text:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of     class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4735)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5197)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1439)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:    java.util.List, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(listTests)]
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:349)
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:322)
at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1360)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1851)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
... 50 more
```

I was checked many times before published this here. And still doesn't understand why I have this mistake

Answer (score 0):

In provided model there is no @Id anotation for class User, but in stacktrace there are nothing about that, so I can assume that you used method level anotation and that could couse exaption like you have, put Id anotation near a fild id, maybe that will help you

Comment: Yep. Thanks! That it was

Answer (score 0):

The exception that is the root cause here is this one:

`org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:    java.util.List, at table: users, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(listTests)]`

I can think of two possible meanings for this exception, and one possible cause for each.

First, it could mean that it can't figure out what the `Test` part of `List<Test>` is referring to. This might be because it is not configured to detect `Test` as a mapped entity class. I do not think this is likely to be the problem, however.

Second, it could mean that it can't figure out what type the column in the database that owns the relationship is supposed to be. This would be because the type of the primary key it would refer to is not defined - in this kind of mapping code, that the class the `@ManyToOne` side refers to does not have an `@Id` field. And sure enough, `User` has no field marked with `@Id`. To fix this, add `@Id` to the `Long id` field in `User`.